# Paste variable in RMariaDB dbGetQuery 'where clause' [1054]

Tags: r, mariadb

Having issues with pasting a variable into the query string for `RMariaDB`. I can return a query without paste and find the proper where statement I am looking for within the dataframe I query (ex. MIN). When I try to use a variable in the query it fails. I have searched stackoverflow up and down and read the dbgetquery docs but nothing seems to be working. I am sure it is something simple, just can't seem to find it.

```
library(RMariaDB)

team <- "MIN"

# This returns entire database with MIN in tm column.
filename <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from nhl_lab_lines_today")

# These will all give me a [1054] error.
test <- paste("select * from nhl_lab_lines_today WHERE tm = ",paste(team,collapse=", "),sep ="")
test <- paste("select * from nhl_lab_lines_today WHERE tm = team")
test <- paste("select * from nhl_lab_lines_today WHERE tm =", team,sep=" ")

filename <- dbGetQuery(conn, test)
```

[image: Query in database]

Comment: You should look into [why this approach can be insecure](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/) - that page also has suggestions for better ways to approach this.

Comment: Thank you for the article. `dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select * from nhl_lab_lines_today WHERE tm = '", MIN ,"'"))`

Answer (score -1):

```
dbGetQuery(con, paste0("select * from nhl_lab_lines_today WHERE tm = '", team ,"'"))
```